# Python script to scan a sharepoint web page and fetch the urls

Tags: python, sharepoint

I am trying to create a Python script that scans a web page on SharePoint and fetches the available URLs from the HTML code.

The SharePoint page also requires credentials and authentication from an app.

But, I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to fetch HTML content from the URL: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for URL
```

Is there a way to scan a SharePoint page without authentication in Python?
or is there a way to authenticate using python?

Following is the script:

```
import re
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
import getpass

def find_urls(html_code):
  # Find URLs after "resolvedUrl\":"
  resolved_urls = re.findall(r'resolvedUrl\\":\\"(.*?)\\"', html_code)

  # Find URLs after "href=\\"
href_urls = re.findall(r'href=\\\\"(.*?)\\\\"', html_code)

return resolved_urls, href_urls

def main():
  url = input("Enter the URL to scan: ")
  username = input("Enter your username: ")
  password = getpass.getpass("Enter your password: ")

  # Fetch HTML content from the URL with NTLM authentication
  try:
    response = requests.get(url, auth=HttpNtlmAuth(username, password))
    response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an exception for HTTP errors
    html_code = response.text

    resolved_urls, href_urls = find_urls(html_code)

    print("\nURLs after resolvedUrl\":\\")
    for url in resolved_urls:
        print(url)

    print("\nURLs after href=\\\\")
    for url in href_urls:
        print(url)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print("Failed to fetch HTML content from the URL:", e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```